# Python - How to get specific 'implied' line in a plot

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

My apologies for the title, I had no idea what to actually put there. Anyways. So i have this plot I made in python.

[image]

for a more thorough background, this is an array that has values (x-axis) that are ran through a multitude of functions (y-axis).

Here is a snippet of my code that focuses on the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [ f_PS(sigma(masses)) for masses in Mact ]
plt.semilogx(Mact,y)
plt.show()
```

NOW, I am very close to getting what I want. But the plot literally traces what I really want to plot, if that makes sense.

How do i fix it to where I eliminate the lines that are currently in the plot and show the 'implied' line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line is "implied", how?

Comment: Look closely, you can see it increase exponentially and and then decrease exponentially at the 1e13 - 1e14 domain.

Comment: So the upper contour of the plots, somehow smoothed through the points which are not connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you need to sort your x and y coordinates by ascending order of x, e.g.:

```
x = np.array(Mact)
y = np.array([ f_PS(sigma(masses)) for masses in Mact ])
idx = np.argsort(x)

plt.semilogx(x[idx], y[idx])
```